# Cordova (ionic) app - render it as demo on a website in the iframe

Tags: angularjs, cordova, iframe, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile app using PhoneGap (Cordova) library with AngularJS and Ionic framework for UI.

I'm wondering if it's possible to render it (in a form of a demo) on the web landing-page (e.g. in an iFrame).

What would be the best approach to do it? I assume I would need some sort of a web-server... Are there any pre-built solutions?

It's just for the purpose of the demo. Doesn't have to be fully-featured.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Do you need to use any "phone" features, or is it just a straight up Angular app? What technology are you using to host the web landing-page?

Comment: I don't need to use any phone features. What I do right now - when developing the app I'm using 'IONIC SERVE' command from terminal, and it starts a server that is serving the app at port localhost:8100.
I'd like to do the same, but not on localhost, just in some production environment, to then iframe that on my web landing-page. I guess - i can take the angular part out of the Cordova package and deploy it somewhere... but still I probably would need some back-end server, (nodejs?) right? I'm new to Angular... The landing page is ruby on rails deployed on Heroku, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, I just realised that's stupid problem. I uploaded the package into FTP and started the site... everything works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `www` folder to your web server and put `<iframe>` on your website like this to showcase your app demo:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/myapp/" width="320" height="568"></iframe>
```